# Why does this singleton behaviour occur?

Tags: .net, vb.net, design-patterns, language-agnostic

One of my junior programmers has created a singleton, but it is acting strangely:

I know you aren't supposed to access object like this, but that's how they did it and I can't explain why this is occurring - After calling remove instance, I put a breakpoint on the line after and I can still access the someObject object and it's properties. This kind of makes sense as your access the reference of the of the mySingleton Object, not the myInstance,... as as you can see I can't explain it clearly, can anyone help?

e.g.

```
    Dim x As MySingleton = MySingleton.GetInstance()

    x.someObject.int = 5
    x.someObject.str = "hello"

    Console.Out.WriteLine(x.someObject.int.ToString)
    Console.Out.WriteLine(x.someObject.str.ToString)

    MySingleton.RemoveInstance()

    Console.Out.WriteLine(x.someObject.int.ToString) //still exists!
    Console.Out.WriteLine(x.someObject.str.ToString) //still exists!
```

Here's the Psuedo Code for the singleton:

```
Public Class MySingleton

    Private Shared _myInstance As MySingleton

    Public someObject As New Class1

    Public Shared Function GetInstance() As MySingleton
        If _myInstance Is Nothing Then
            _myInstance = New MySingleton
        End If
        Return _myInstance

    End Function

    Public Shared Sub RemoveInstance()
        _myInstance = Nothing
    End Sub


    End Class
```

Personally I don't write my singletons like this - I have the instance object as a separate class. but each to their own.

Comment: Important point: that `_myInstance` usage *isn't* a singleton, and isn't thread-safe. In particular if that is ASP.NET (or any other highly-threaded environment) you are going to have chaos.

Comment: I forgot to mention - I'd expect a null ref exception after calling remove instance...

Comment: @Marc - yes I know, I've simplified the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, in .NET you can never explicitly/deterministically set an object to nothing. You can only set its references to Nothing and then allow the garbage collector to clean it up.  As already stated, in your original code you actually retained a reference to it by assigning it to x.

In general, setting an object to Nothing or null is not suggested because an object is eligible for garbage collection after the last reference; the runtime notices this. For example, if you have code like this:

```
Dim anObject as new MyObject

anObject.DoAnOperation()
[1]
... 
...
'more code
...
...

Set anObject = Nothing
[2]
```

If you did not set the object to Nothing, it would be eligible for collection anytime after point [1]. If you do, it is not eligible until point [2]. If your method takes a long time to complete, it could become important.

More info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx

Answer (score 6):

It is because you only removed the `MySingleton._myInstance` reference to the object.

`x` still has a reference to that object.

**Edit:**
To clarify:

it is like:

```
var A = new Class();
var B = A;
A = null;
// Here B still has that reference to the created object
```

Comment: by setting _myInstance to nothing, shouldn't all references to that reference object now point to nothing?

Comment: What your saying I know is true, what I don't understand is if I were to change a.property to something, b.property would automatically equal that as it is a reference type pointing to object a... why does the name not apply to setting the object to nothing?

Comment: @Mr Shoubs, No, you are not killing the object, just removing that handle/reference to it. All other references are still holding on to that object.

Comment: @Mr Shoubs, No, Why should they? Say if I have an employee object with a name property and I do string empname =employee.Name; then dispose of employee, you want empname cleared too?  To be pedantic, strings are different in that assignment is overloaded and the string is interned, but the point remains...

Comment: Incidently, Its important to grasp that  early, cos when you get to events, lambdas and memory leaks,figuring out what still could hold a reference to your object is the only real solution!

Comment: @Overflow - good explanation, but string are mutable, so it isn't a great example... it's more like a value type.

Answer (score 4):

The first line gets a reference to your singleton, and that reference will remain valid until the object is garbage collected. However, as long as there are still references to an object it will not be garbage collected - so you will continue to have a reference to a valid object until you explicitly assign x to something else.

Comment: This makes sense, - I've just noticed he's storing the singleton as a member varible